# Is there an SQL Server function to remove brackets and their contents?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, function, replace

I need to remove all brackets and their contents from multiple records but I can't figure out the best way to do this.

I would like to be able to write something like

```
SELECT dbo.RemoveBracketedText(ColumnName) FROM TableName;
```

And it would convert a record such as 'Hello (World)' to just 'Hello '

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Google picked up : http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=98328

Comment: I tried a few Google results, they didn't quite work right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first approach would probably have been to write a quick c# app to do it or use SSIS and write a package to take care of it, but if your determined to use tsql... it will likely require a combination of a recursive function and some string manipulation.

This is minimally tested but should be close.  (i.e. it worked on the sample text you provide in your question).

```
CREATE FUNCTION RemoveBracketedText (@sourceString varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @pStart Int
DECLARE @pEnd Int
DECLARE @pTarget varchar(max)
DECLARE @pResult varchar(max)

SET @pStart = CHARINDEX('(', @sourceString)
SET @pEnd = CHARINDEX(')', @sourceString, @pStart) /** start looking from pos of opening bracket */

IF @pEnd > @pStart AND @pEnd > 0  /** basic error avoidance */
BEGIN
  SET @pTarget = SUBSTRING(@sourceString, @pStart, @pEnd - @pStart + 1)
  SET @pResult = Replace(@sourceString, @pTarget, '')

  /** recursion to get rid of more than one set of brackets per string */
  IF CHARINDEX('(', @pResult) > 0 AND CHARINDEX(')', @pResult) > CHARINDEX('(', @pResult)
  BEGIN
    SET @pResult = dbo.RemoveBracketedText(@pResult)  
  END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SET @pResult = @sourceString  /** no matching set of brackets found */
END

RETURN @pResult
END
```

Comment: Thanks, I will implement and let you know if it takes care of my needs. Looks like it should be good though!

Comment: I made one more little edit.  I added @pStart to the charindex that finds the closing bracket.  Note my edit above.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't resist.  I also added some basic error avoidance... i.e. making sure the opening bracket has a closing.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ltrim(rtrim(
  replace(
    replace(ColumnName, 
      substring(ColumnName, 
                charindex('(',ColumnName), 
                charindex(')',ColumnName) - charindex('(',ColumnName) + 1), 
      ''), 
  '  ',' ')
)) from TableName;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.